# Enable chrome SafeBrowsing error with puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, safe-browsing

`Google Safe Browsing` shows client side warning page when browsing to a malicious web site.

For example, navigating to https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/s/malware.html will display:
[image: client side warning page]

However, when using `puppeteer` this warning page is not shown.

Is it possible to enable this error screen in puppeteer, or to detect it will be shown if using the browser?

I have tried to:

1. Use the local `Chrome` instead of `Chromium`
2. set `ignoreDefaultArgs` to true (run without puppeteer default flags):

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
  });
```

3. Played with various possible related flags [see here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

However the warning page was never displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try launching puppeteer with the 'userDataDir' argument? 
Using a predefined user directory should enable web security capabilities.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
    userDataDir: '/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome'
  });
```